# How to, in AngularJS, use $http to update persistent memory

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http

This is code from an Angular introduction video series, which explains how to populate angular controllers with data from persisted memory, but stops just short of explaining how to add the new product reviews to the persisted memory.

There do seem to be some articles explaining how to do this, but since I am very new to angular, I'm afraid I couldn't understand any of them.

I have figured out the syntax for making post requests using $http, but I don't see how to fit that code into the existing structure, so that it will 1) be called when pushing a new element to the reviews array, and 2) update the view when completed.

I am interested to learn a basic way to add the new product review to persistent memory.

```
(function() {
  var app = angular.module('gemStore', ['store-directives']);

  app.controller('StoreController', ['$http', function($http){
    var store = this;
    store.products = [];
    $http.get('/store-products.json').success(function(data){
      store.products = data;
    });
  }]);

  app.controller('ReviewController', function() {
    this.review = {};

    this.addReview = function(product) {
      product.reviews.push(this.review);

      this.review = {};
    };
  });
})();
```

The JSON looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Azurite",
    "description": "...",
    ...
    "reviews": []
  },
  ...
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `store-products.json` is just a file on the server, you'll need an actual backend implementation (in PHP, nodejs, etc.) to actually update the file (or more typically just return the content from the database).

Normally you would make a save method and not post on every modification, though. But, in either case, depending on your backend, usually the implementation is as simple as `$http.put('/store-products', store.products)` whenever you click a "save" button. Typically, the put can return the same data, so there's typically no need to update the view since you just set it exactly to your state. But, if you have possibility of concurrent editing, and the put returns the modified data, it would look like your get:

```
$http.put('/store-products', store.products).success(function(data){
  store.products = data;
});
```

For adding an item, it might almost identical, depending on your data model:

```
$http.post('/store-products', newProduct).success(function(data){
  store.products = data;
});
```

In this case the POST gives an item to add and returns all of the products. If there are a lot of products -- that is, products are more like a large database than a small set in a "document", then the post would more typically return the added item after any server processing:

```
$http.post('/store-products', newProduct).success(function(newProductFromServer){
  store.products.push(newProductFromServer); //if newProduct wasn't already in the array
  //or, store.products[newProductIdx] = newProductFromServer
});
```

If you really wanted to call this function on every modification instead of a save button, you can use a [watch](https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.25/docs/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope):

```
$scope.$watchCollection(
  function() { return store.products; },
  function() { /* call the $http.put or post here */ }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the input, Jason.

For the kind of operation that this represents, posting a review on a product page, I really do feel like an immediate server update is appropriate. 

When I get a minute, I will try this out. 

I may have a follow up question, because, as I mentioned, this is fairly new to me.

Comment: OK, I see what you are thinking. OK, in this case I usually have a "GET" items, "PUT" items, and "POST" a new item. So I would do a POST to store-products.json with the single product I was adding, and the backend returns all products. Then the $http call looks like `$http.post('/products/123/reviews', reviewToAdd).success(function(data) { /* update local copy */ } ));` where 123 is your product ID. So in this case the URL says "add review to product 123" and "return the modified product" (or return modified reviews array)

Comment: I'm wondering if it is even possible to make changes to a serverside .json file in this way. If not, I'll build a php wrapper

Comment: You do need to write a backend to have a dynamic website. Maybe if you were using something like Apache and WebDAV it could theoretically be possible to not have to write any backend code, although I've never heard of such an attempt. There are also cloud-hosted services like firebase. But it will be very hard to build anything secure without a backend running trusted code.

Comment: Jason, I've been able to get this working. Thank you for your help. If you edit your answer to include what we've talked about in comments (That the .json file isn't sufficient, and that the AJAX request that populates the data needs to be called within the post success callback) then I'd be happy to 'accept' your answer. Send me a message if you want, to let me know it's ready.